# Ember routing out from modal doesn't render correct content into the outlet

Tags: templates, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, routes, coffeescript

I have problem with Ember.js and Bootstrap 3.0 modal.
Here is the sample jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Bs32/9/

My modal is implemented as subroute for the dynamic segment.

If you enter the `test` route and then open the modal, everything works OK.

But if you follow the route directly to the `test.contact` (clicking second link from `test.index` path), and then follow the link to `other` route from modal, the content of `test` is not removed and `other` route is inserted before the content of `test` route.

Can anyone give me a hint if the problem here is Bootstrap's modal or Ember itself?
Should I file a bug report for Ember or Bootstrap, or I did something wrong?

Thanks

Damian

Answer (score 0):

I should implement modals based on routes see this article...

http://nerdyworm.com/blog/2013/04/20/ember-modal-example/

The code is outdated but easy to adapt to newest ember versions.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I saw that blogpost already. Having modals working is not the problem here, but switching the routes in Ember and not clearing the old content of the outlet is. Modal is rendered in named outlet and it shows/hides as it should.